# How email a PHP webpage with correct format to any email client?

Tags: php, email, html

I am having a problem about emailing a PHP page with correct format. The page contain table with made of simple `<TD>` and `<TR>` and a javascript for making negative numbers turn in to red, the javascript is show as below:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 td.negative { color : red; }
</style>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MakeNegative() {
    TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i=0; i<TDs.length; i++) {
            var temp = TDs[i];
            if (temp.firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) temp.className = "negative";
        }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<~~~~~~~tables goes here~~~~~~~>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
MakeNegative();
//-->
</script>
</body>
```

I can display the webpage with correct format using internet browser:

[image]

but when I mail it with PHPMailer or mailsend.exe, the format become confused, no more negative number in red and table is messed up. Below is the screenshot for sending to a Gmail account:

[image]

and here is the screenshot for sending to a Outlook(hotmail) account:

(You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links...... I'd better post the link in comment, please check, thanks)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: screenshot for hotmail account: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cp2g.png

Comment: i dont have a good answer for you, but you might want to reconsider your approach.  The PHP application is more than capable of creating an html email template that doesnt need javascript to format it for you.  I don't know for sure but with the variations in how javascript is implemented across the browsers (which agreed to a standard) I wonder how they are implemented in email browsers.  I suspect this will work fine in most cases but won't in others.  If you want it to work all the time have the php app do the work.  My opinion on this, not an answer.  Good luck with this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use inline css, a lot of web email providers disable css style in style block like:

```
<style>
</style>
```

So, really you need:

```
<td style="color: red;">-1</td>
```

for each.

Also, it has been pointed out that this creation can be done purely in PHP. Although, it doesn't seem like you're having a problem with that. If you use all inline styles, you will be fine.

When you pull the data out of the DB, just construct your rows that way:

```
$tableRows = '';
foreach($dbRows as $row) {
    $number = $row['number'];
    if ($number < 0) {
      $tableRows .= '<tr><td style="color: red;">'.$number.'</td></tr>';
    } else {
      $tableRows .= '<tr><td>'.$number.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

//$tableRows will contain all of your row data as HTML now.

You could do this with much less code, but I wanted to illustrate the point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am fetching row from mysql database and the number can be positive or negative so it can't just add style color in each line of <td>. Therefore, I use javascript to auto determine it and get it done, but it is not working after sending out. Would you mind to tell more about how to purely done it by PHP, thanks.

Comment: @user602525 Small note on the color declaration part. It is better supported in html email to use html's bgcolor="#770000" than using CSS. Also, you should always use the 6-digit hex code when declaring colors.